# How to block direct requests to php files in specified directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, include

I have a master folder where I hold all of my resources such as js, css, images, etc. called /resources/.

In /resources/, I have php files I include on pages of my website, however, they're currently directly accessible if entered into the browser.

Is there a way for me to use .htaccess in that directory to prevent direct requests to any files of certain extensions such as PHP?
Hotlinking prevention isn't really what I'm looking for. I just need a way to kill any sort of direct request to these PHP files(in the /resources/ directory specifically) made by anything other than the website itself.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't you move the php files out of the web-root?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a `.htaccess` in your `/resources/` folder containing the following

```
<Files ~ "\.php$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

It should prevent access to all `.php` files

Comment: So this will still allow all "requires" or "includes" on pages to access them though, correct?

Comment: Is that tilde and the 2 spaces between it and "Files" necessary or just aesthetic?

Comment: It's a regular expression, see documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files

Comment: Are the 2 spaces a typo then? That document shows one space only on each side of the tilde.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, but it doesn't change a thing, the file works

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your assistance. Setting your answer as correct.